# Category with two types of morphisms and a weak transitive like relationship between them

Tags: ct.category-theory

Take a category A that has two types of morphism structures on it (can think of it as two separate categories over the same objects) which we call type $a$ and type $b$. Then if $g_b f_a$ exists there exists $h_a = g_b f_a$. [possibly also requiring $g_a$ but this seems less interesting]

I'm trying to capture the abstract concept of "if x steals from y and y gives to z then z steals from x" where we have two distinct morphism types (steals and gives in this example) that have a transitive-like relationship.

E.g., we see that in our concept of money, wealth, etc that some people steal wealth from others. They then give, through whatever means such as "speaking fees", "bribes", etc , that wealth to other individuals and those individuals who were "given" that money are not considered thieves, generally speaking. But, essentially it is steal theft disguised as a gift or payment to obfuscate the theft.

Many societies have laws about stolen goods such as even if you buy stolen goods "legitimately" (in belief) you effectively have stolen them (you can be convicted of theft if the powers decide so). We also have in all societies thieves, being thieves, who will pass stolen money/goods around and technically the recipient of the stolen money/goods is not considered a thief (exactly the opposite of the stolen goods).

I'm trying to capture the first idea (what law tries to capture) by essentially saying that one type of morphism dominates others in a composition.

There may be better ways to codify such a concept but wondering if anything is out there already.

Comment: You could start by looking up the notion of **double category** and searching for variations on that which people have considered.

Comment: Do you need any condition on the identity arrows? If type a identity arrows act as type b identity arrows, then the type b morphisms inject into the type a ones. But if this is the case, the condition you suggest is actually not that interesting, and what results is just a category equipped with a wide subcategory. So you probably need to rule something out to avoid such a collapse.

Comment: @DavidRoberts No, they are not the same - stealing is not the same as giving. It will be true that $h_a = g_b i_a$ and this $h_a$ must exist but it is precisely this $h_a$ that aliases the $g_b$ and makes "paid = theft" after a theft takes place(if an $f_a != i_a$ exists). Essentially it's to capture the idea of a_1 ... a_j ... b_(j+1) ... b_n is is a sequence of a's and the b's are acting as aliases for a's. Basically it's state that any downstream aliasing is artificial. So in some sense you are right(there will be cases where the identity arrows are the same and in that case it willcollapse

Comment: @PaulTaylor I don't think a double category works. Maybe there is some way to transform the concepts in to it but it seems to be over my head.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I guess the way to think about it is that the type a dominates b if a "precedes" b in a composition chain. Maybe think of coloring a directed graph with two types of edges where the color(say red and blue) of the second type depends on if the type of edges before it. The only edges of type blue would, in a sense, be "pure" edge chains. Also similar, say, to blood lines. If say type a is a "contamination" then it will contaminate all those downstream.